# How to solve an equation in R with mean and SD?

Tags: r

I have to resolve both equations that you can see in the graph (see below)

`y1 = 38 + 0.067 x`

and

`y2 = 38 + 0.047 x`

for a x value of `x = 70`

My goal is to get y values (which is easy to get manually) AND a standard deviation.
Is there any way to get it with R ?

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: I think you are looking at linear regression with just one sample.

Comment: Yes, really easy to get it manually, but with R? any help ?

Comment: ` think you are looking at linear regression with just one sample` - `Yes` -> but that seems to be impossible- there are infinitely many lines you can draqw through **one** point?! But  I might be missing something?!

Comment: @dario, not sure about your point, or maybe I do not get it. The equation I got seems to fit with my data. Maybe I have to an interpolation to get the y value at x = 70 ?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you are looking at regression model i.e. using [`lm`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/lm) in R. However to use it, you need to have a `y` variable. So based on the given `x` and `y`, the model will learn `beta` i.e. coefficients which gives the best result, in this case `Rˆ2`.

So, in case you don't have a `y` and want to use the above equation, you can write a simple function, something like:

```
compute_y = function(intercept = 38, x=70, coefficient){
  y <- intercept + (coefficient * x)
  sdev <-  sd(y)
  return(list(y = y, sdev=  sdev))
}

y1 <- compute_y(coefficient=0.067)
y2 <- compute_y(coefficient=0.047)
```

This should give the `y` values. However, to calculate standard deviation, you need a vector of x or y values, you can't calculate `sd` for a scalar value.

Comment: Good, it is working well. thank you! But what about the SD ? The "grey zone" around the linear regression ?

Comment: Thank you, it gives me NA values. But after a reflexion, I think I have to a interpolation first to obtain a mean and SD value at 70 %. But I am not able to run it. Thanks!